# IP controll cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, ip

I created a IP check in my AppController:

```
if (Configure::read('access.ipcontrol') === "y") {
            if (! $this->Ipcheck->check($this->request->clientIp())) {
                $this->ipaccess = FALSE;
                $this->Auth->autoRedirect = FALSE;
                $this->Flash->error(__('No access for IP number' . ' ' . $this->request->clientIp()));
                $this->redirect = array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'noright');
                return;
            }
}
```

Allowed for access without login are:

```
$this->Auth->allow([
                'index',
                'logout',
                'login',
                'noaccess',
                'noright'
        ]);
```

When I access my App from a none valid IP I get the error message 'No access for IP number  ...', AND a redirect to the login page.

How can I  get only the error message **without** the redirection?

Comment: can't you set `unauthorizedRedirect` in the auth component? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options

Comment: I put `$this->Auth->config('unauthorizedRedirect', '/');`in the beforeFilter section in the AppController which has no effect.

Comment: just set it to array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'noright')